# MVVM: how to pass a resources string from view model to view?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-resources

I want to display a text in my view. However, the text is not dependent of "data" from my model I can display directly but depends on a state enum. Dependent of the state I want to display a pre-defined text in my string resources file.

For example, I have the following enum in the model layer:

```
enum class GreetingType
{
    GREETING_FIRST_TIME,
    WELCOME_BACK,
    GOODBYE
}
```

In my strings.xml I have the respective strings:

```
R.string.greeting_first_time
R.string.welcome_back
R.string.goodbye
```

My question is: How should the interface between view model and view look like? Should I pass:

1. the enum (e.g. `GreetingType.GOODBYE`)
2. the resource ID (e.g. `R.string.goodbye`)
3. the resolved string (e.g. `context.resources.getString(R.string.goodbye`)

Each approach seems to have downsides:

- With 1. and 2. I need the mapping logic in the view.
- With 3. I need `context` in the view model, which I would like to avoid.

Is there a recommended approach?

Can I achieve both:

- Keep the view dumb (by avoiding if/else)
- Keep the view model clean of the Android Framework (i.e. use `ViewModel` instead of `AndroidViewModel`)?

The examples I found only deal with data being displayed directly.

Comment: The worst thing to do is adding context to viewModel
Check it out : https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54

Answer (score 3):

For me, the better choice is to use android [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

Thanks to data binding, your view (.xml) have variables. So you can pass your `viewModel` directly into your view.

It is not a downside to map simple logic into your view. In web development, this is what we do with React or VueJs in template. The most import is to keep it simple.

From this point of view, when you want to change something, you know that your `display logic` is every time in your `view`.

If your display logic is going to be more complex, you can create a [Binding Adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

Here is an example:

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    // prevent changing the value of the greeting var outside the viewModel
    private val _greeting = MutableLiveData<GreetingType>()

    // we can access greeting value from here
    val greeting: LiveData<GreetingType>
        get() = _greeting

    fun setGreeting(g: GreetingType) {
        if (_greeting.value != g) {
            _greeting.value = g
        }
    }

}
```

Your fragment :

```
class MyFragment() : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: MyFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // init your viewModel here
        // [...]

        binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        return binding.root

    }

}
```

Your data binding object :

```
object MyFirstDatabinding {

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("android:dispGreeting")
    fun displayGreeting(txtView: TextView, greeting: GreetingType?) {
        greeting?.let { g ->
            val sentence = when(g) {
                GREETING_FIRST_TIME -> view.context.getString(R.string.greeting_first_time)
                WELCOME_BACK -> view.context.getString(R.string.welcome_back)
                GOODBYE -> view.context.getString(R.string.goodbye)
            }
            txtView.setText(sentence)
        }
    }

}
```

Your view

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="your.package.MyViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:dispGreeting="@{viewModel.greeting}" />

    </ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked into data binding yet because I wanted to avoid having logic in XML files. I didn't know about binding adapters. This seems to fulfill what I was looking for. 
Do you have experience with writing unit tests for binding adapters? That could look like the major advantage over having the logic in the view.

Comment: I readed tons of solutions which to solve this problem. Your idea is completely satisfied me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case, but it is not ideal to have resource references inside viewModels as well. So I would suggest you assign it directly in view (activity or fragment) e.g:

```
fun setGreeting() { textView.setText(R.string.greeting_first_time) }
fun setWelcome() { textView.setText(R.string.welcome_back) }
fun setGoodbye() { textView.setText(R.string.goodbye) }
```

Then display them on your view model e.g. if this then do setGreeting() if that then do setWelcome() or do a switch case with your enum and call the corresponding view().setGreeting() inside your viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

To use the context in `ViewModel` you can use `AndroidViewModel(application)` which needs the `applicationContext` and then you the ressources.

example from [Android Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-internet-data/), here is the [repo](https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-mars-real-estate):

```kotlin
val displayPropertyPrice = Transformations.map(selectedProperty) {
    application.applicationContext.getString(
            when (it.isRental) {
                true -> R.string.display_price_monthly_rental
                false -> R.string.display_price
            }, it.price)
}
```

Comment: This is a bad practice, especially if your strings need to be localized. Strings resolved with application context won't respect the configuration change that happens when you change languages in the system settings, as the application context is not re-created on configuration change like an Activity's.

Comment: That is the downside indeed of using application context. Another solution would be to simply set the `displayPropertyPrice` with the `R.string.something` and in the View with observe use the current context to set the text with the string